# text = response.text AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy

I use `parse` method to save some `html` files on local then i want to parse them. but i got `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'`

I know i could separate this process into two method, which means that first i save these `html` files then second pass to the other method and parse them. But i need to save and parse in the same method.

And here's my code

```
def parse(self, response):

    sel = Selector(response)
    company = CompanyItem()     

    total_results_count = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='totalResultsCount big']").text
    if total_results_count >3:
        person_1 = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr:nth-child(1) > td.personName > a")))
        person_1.click()

        person_profile = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "profileSectionContent")))
        html_source = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='personSummaryTable']").get_attribute("outerHTML")
        f = open('person_1_%s.html'%(company['c_name']), 'w')
        f.write(html_source.encode('utf-8'))
        f.close()
        person_path = 'file:///Users/cengcengruihong/Desktop/scrapy_learning/zoominfo_test/' + 'person_1_%s.html'%(company['c_name'])
        cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()

        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(person_path)
        company['p1c_name'] = sel.xpath("//h1[@itemprop='name']/text()").extract_first().strip("\n")
        company['p1c_role'] = sel.xpath("//h2[@itemprop='role']/text()").extract_first().strip("\n")
        company['p1c_phoneNumber'] = sel.xpath("//div[@class='phoneNumber']/text()[position()=2]").extract_first().strip("\n")
        company['p1c_email'] = sel.xpath("//span[@class='personEmail']/a/text()").extract_first().strip()

        yield company
```

Someone give me a hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='totalResultsCount big']").text` It's returning a string i guess. Try to print it and it's type before calling `.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is here

```
person_path = 'file:///Users/cengcengruihong/Desktop/scrapy_learning/zoominfo_test/' + 'person_1_%s.html'%(company['c_name'])
    cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()

    sel = HtmlXPathSelector(person_path)
```

You pass filename to the Selector's constructor while it expects `Response` object as first parameter. To create Selector from file content you should do something like that:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

with open(person_path) as fp:
    sel = Selector(text=fp.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to parse your HTML using Scrapy.

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
response = HtmlResponse(url="", body='<div id="test">Test text</div>')
response.xpath('//div[@id="test"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
```

You can read your file's content and then pass this to `body` parameter.